# How to click a button in angular 2?

Tags: html, forms, angular, typescript

Without involving Jquery, how can the javascript of a component click an HTML button? All the documentation is for the opposite interaction of a button being on the page and handling that click, which won't work because it belongs to a `ngNoForm`  element that the browser needs to handle itself.

Comment: Here is an example, `document.getElementById( "exit-cancel" ).querySelector( "a" ).click()` there is no angular2 in here, just js

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation for that, and I thank you. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a normal javascript click

Here is the doc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Here is an example code

```
document.getElementById( "exit-cancel" ).querySelector( "a" ).click()
```